# How to increase DPI from 96 to 150

Tags: software-recommendation, dpi

I have a JPG logo that is 96dpi and needs to be minimum of 150dpi. What program do I use?

Comment: DPI values can be changed freely on JPG files. They don't have much meaning when they're not related to a fixed size. If the size should stay constant, an increase of DPI (= upscaling) of an image will lower the quality of the image. Moreso with JPG images that will be recompressed with each time you save them.

Answer (score 1):

Try SmillaEnlarger.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/imageenlarger/

It's a freeware image resizer. You can increase pixel dimensions without making the image unsharp. The program tries to calculate the simplest possible higher resolution image from which the low resolution image could have been downscaled. Of course it cannot invent missing details, but sharp borders stay sharp.

There's also ON1 Resize, a commercial program for the same purpose. It has been available 20 years. Former names: Genuine Fractals, Perfect Resize

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop (paid with free trial) or Gimp (free) can do this. Be advised increasing the dpi count in a JPG image will affect the sharpness and overall quality of the image.

For best results logos are usually circulated in vector format (AI, EPS, SVG, etc). Which can then be exported to 150 or 300dpi with no quality loss.

Answer (score 0):

If your logo is quite simple you can trace it through image trace in illustrator. That will convert your bitmap image into vector artwork which can easily be scaled without quality loss.